# Making a dictionary? from 2 lists / columns

Tags: python-2.7

I have a large database with several columns, i need data from 2 of these.

The end result is to have 2 drop down menus where the first one sets "names" and the second one is the "numbers" values that has been merged into the name. I just need the data available so i can input it into another program.

So a list or dictionary that contains the Unique values of the "names" list, with the numbers from the numbers list appended to them.

```
# Just a list of random names and numbers for testing
names = [
    "Cindi Brookins",
    "Cumberband Hamberdund",
    "Roger Ramsden",
    "Cumberband Hamberdund",
    "Lorean Dibble",
    "Lorean Dibble",
    "Coleen Snider",
    "Rey Bains",
    "Maxine Rader",
    "Cindi Brookins",
    "Catharine Vena",
    "Lanny Mckennon",
    "Berta Urban",
    "Rey Bains",
    "Roger Ramsden",
    "Lanny Mckennon",
    "Catharine Vena",
    "Berta Urban",
    "Maxine Rader",
    "Coleen Snider"
]

numbers = [
    6,
    5,
    7,
    10,
    3,
    9,
    1,
    1,
    2,
    7,
    4,
    2,
    8,
    3,
    8,
    10,
    4,
    9,
    6,
    5
]
```

So in the above example "Berta Urban" would appear once, but still have the numbers 8 and 9 assigned, "Rey Bains" would have 1 and 3.

I have tried with

```
mergedlist = dict(zip(names, numbers))
```

But that only assigns the last of the numbers to the name.

I am not sure if i can make a dictionary with Unique "names" that holds multiple "numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get the last number associated with each name because dictionary keys are unique (otherwise they wouldn't be much use). So if you do

```
mergedlist["Berta Urban"] = 8
```

and after that

```
mergedlist["Berta Urban"] = 9
```

the result will be

```
{'Berta Urban': 9}
```

Just as if you did:

```
berta_urban = 8
berta_urban = 9
```

In that case you would expect the value of `berta_urban` to be `9` and not `[8,9]`.

So, as you can see, you need an `append` not an assignment to your `dict` entry.

```
from collections import defaultdict
mergedlist = defaultdict(list)
for (name,number) in zip(names, numbers): mergedlist[name].append(number)
```

This gives:

```
 {'Coleen Snider': [1, 5], 
  'Cindi Brookins': [6, 7],
  'Cumberband Hamberdund': [5, 10],
  'Roger Ramsden': [7, 8],
  'Lorean Dibble': [3, 9],
  'Rey Bains': [1, 3],
  'Maxine Rader': [2, 6],
  'Catharine Vena': [4, 4],
  'Lanny Mckennon': [2, 10],
  'Berta Urban': [8, 9]
}
```

which is what I think you want. Note that you will get duplicates, as in `'Catharine Vena': [4, 4]` and you will also get a list of numbers for each name, even if the list has only one number in it.

Comment: Thank you, this also worked. Got something to go on now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple keys of the same name in a dict, but your dict keys can be unique while holding a list of matching numbers. Something like:

```
mergedlist = {}
for i, v in enumerate(names):
    mergedlist[v] = mergedlist.get(v, []) + [numbers[i]]

print(mergedlist["Berta Urban"])  # prints [8, 9]
```

Not terribly efficient, tho. In dependence of the datatbase you're using, chances are that the database can get you the results in the form you prefer faster than you post-processing and reconstructing the data.